# PHP - Array fatal error

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an odd error in my PHP code regarding dynamic arrays.

The error outputted is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array ... on line 89
```

This is a portion of my code, it is within a foreach loop, which is looping through settings in a database:

```
foreach($query->fetchAll() as $row)
{
    if($site!=CURRENT_SITE_TEMPLATE)
    {
        $property = 'foreignSettings';
        $propertyType = 'foreignSettingsTypes';
    } else {
        $property = 'settings';
        $propertyType = 'settingTypes';
    }

    $this->$property[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']] = $row['variable_value'];
    settype($this->$property[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']],$row['variable_type']);

    $this->$propertyType[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']] = $row['variable_type'];
}
```

For the sake of the example code, `$site` is 'admin' and `CURRENT_SITE_TEMPLATE` is 'admin'.
In addition, `$foreignSettings, $foreignSettingsTypes, $settings, and $settingTypes` are all defined as arrays in the class scope

The error is on line 89, which is:

```
$this->$property[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']] = $row['variable_value'];
```

I originally thought it was because of the $property variable accesing the array, however, this looks like valid legal code in the PHP documentation ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php in `example #1`)

Any help on this error would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the settings or foreignSettings property an array? var_dump($this->$property) and check what is in there.

Comment: I don't know how it should be, but try one of the following and see if it is ok: `$this->{$property[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']]}` or `$this->{$property}[$row['variable_section']][$row['variable_name']]` (the 2nd one should be ok)

Comment: yeah right the second one should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as follows: `$this->$property[0]` means you access the 0th place of $property which in your case would be the first letter of the string $property. Thus you end up with $this->f or $this->s.

with `$this->$property[0][0]` you would be trying to access the 0th place of the 0th place of the $property string what results in an error because you try to access the 0th place of the char s what is not possible since the char s can not be referenced as an array.

what you want is `$this->{$propperty}[0][0]` what means that you try to access the 0th place of the 0th place of the variable that has the name $propperty.

Answer (score 1):

In your given example `$property` is a string. You are then trying to use that as an array. Strings only has numeric indexes (if you need to use as an array).